# Как задать javascript событие на движение мыши в 10% от левого края окна браузера?

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать левый  sidenav.

Нужно чтобы срабатывало javascript событие, когда пользователь направляет курсор в левый край окна браузера (например 10% от левого края), как  это сделать ?

Comment: было бы неплохо, если бы Вы показали проблему, с которой столкнулись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле все очень просто.

Создаем элемент разметки, который по умолчанию не виден, далее вешаем событие на `onMouseMove` для документа, **если координата по x меньше 10% от ширины**, то показываем элемент, с логикой скрытия чуть сложнее - нужно скрывать меню в том случае, **если координата по x превышает размер меню***. Ниже накидал быстрый скетч, если будут вопросы - задавайте.

```js
function bind(func, context) {
  return function() { // (*)
    return func.apply(context, arguments);
  };
}

var curObj = {
  curState: false,
  w: window,
  d: document,
  e: document.documentElement,
  g: document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
  menu: document.getElementById('menu'),
  hideMenu: function() {
    this.menu.style.opacity = 0;
    this.curState = false;
  },
  unHideMenu: function() {
    this.menu.style.opacity = 1;
    this.curState = true;
  },
  onMM: function(evt) {
    var w = this.w.innerWidth || this.e.clientWidth || this.g.clientWidth;
    var mouseX = evt.clientX;

    if (this.curState) {
      // Мы сейчас показываем меню
      // Если мы ушли за пределы меню то его нужно скрыть
      if (mouseX > 200) {
        this.hideMenu();
      }
    } else {
      // Мы сейчас не показываем меню
      // Если курсор в левой части экрана 10% то нужно показать меню
      if (mouseX / w < 0.1) {
        this.unHideMenu();
      }
    }
  }
};

curObj.onMM = bind(curObj.onMM, curObj);



document.addEventListener("mousemove", curObj.onMM);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

#content {
  width: 400px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#content h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#menu {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 17px 10px 29px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 17px 10px 29px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 17px 10px 29px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  My tea's gone cold. I'm wondering why I got out of bed at all. The morning rain clouds up my window. And I can't see at all. And even if I could it'd all be gray. But your picture on my wall. It reminds me that it's not so bad, it's not so bad.
</div>

<div id="content">
  <h1>Нужно поводить курсором по странице</h1>
  <p>When you walked through the door. It was clear to me (Clear to me). You’re the one they adore. Who they came to see (Who they came to see). You’re a rock star (Baby). Everybody wants you (Everybody wants you). Player, who can really blame you? (Who
    can really blame you?). We’re the ones who made you.
  </p>
  <p>
    I never meant to give you mushrooms, girl. I never meant to bring you to my world. Now you sitting in the corner crying. And now it's my fault, my fault. I never meant to give you mushrooms, girl. I never meant to bring you to my world. Now you sitting
    in the corner crying. And now it's my fault, my fault.
  </p>
  <p>
    We're gonna rock this house until we knock it down. So turn the volume loud. 'Cause it's mayhem 'til the A.M.. So, baby, make just like K-Fed. And let yourself go, let yourself go. Say "Fuck it!" before we kick the bucket. Life's too short to not go for
    broke. So everybody, everybody, go berserk, grab your vial, yeah.
  </p>
</div>
```